# Database Structure , Eav model , too slow search queries

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, database-design

I'm creating a car-seller website. I have a `car_properties` table to store my car properties, such as ABS, Climate, Navigation, Alarm, etc.

I'm using EAV model for `car properties` table, so my table looks like:

```
id , name , value , car_id
```

my main table for cars : `car_sale` table :

```
id, price , brand , mode , year
```

But for 1 car i have about 25-30 rows in `car_properties` table. Think this for 300 cars , it will be about 9000 rows in `car_properties` table.

I have a detailed search option on my home page.

```
search filters : Brand , Model , Location , Year-to-Year , Price-to-price , condition , tranmission and so on
```

But when i add jus 2 or 3 cars , it works too slow! my search query like :

```
        $query = CarSale::
          where('car_model_id', '=', $model_id)
        ->join("car_properties as cp1", "cp1.car_for_sale_id", "=", "car_for_sale.id")
        ->join("car_properties as cp2 ", "cp2.car_for_sale_id", "=", "cp1.car_for_sale_id")
        ->join("car_properties as cp3 ", "cp3.car_for_sale_id", "=", "cp2.car_for_sale_id")
        ->join("car_properties as cp4 ", "cp4.car_for_sale_id", "=", "cp3.car_for_sale_id")
        ->join("car_properties as cp5 ", "cp5.car_for_sale_id", "=", "cp4.car_for_sale_id")
        ->join("car_properties as cp6 ", "cp6.car_for_sale_id", "=", "cp5.car_for_sale_id")
        ->groupBy('car_for_sale.id')
        ->select('car_for_sale.*' );


    if($year1!='' and $year2!=''){
        $query->where('year', '>=' , $year1 )->where('year', '<=' , $year2);
    }
    if($price1!='' and $price2!=''){
        $query->where('price', '>=' , $price1 )->where('price', '<=' , $price2);
    }
    if($location!=''){
        $query->where("cp1.name",'=',"location")
              ->where("cp1.value",'like',"%$location%");
    }
    if($condition!=''){
        $query->where("cp2.name",'=',"condition")
              ->where("cp2.value",'like',"%$condition%");
    }
    if($transmition!=''){
        $query->where("cp3.name",'=',"gearbox")
              ->where("cp3.value",'like',"%$transmition%");
    }
    if($wheel!=''){
        $query->where("cp4.name",'=',"steering_wheel")
              ->where("cp4.value",'like',"%$wheel%");
    }
    if($fuel!=''){
        $query->where("cp5.name",'=',"fuel_type")
              ->where("cp5.value",'like',"%$fuel%");
    }
    if($imported!=''){
        $query->where("cp6.name",'=',"customs")
              ->where("cp6.value",'=',$imported);
    }

    $results = $query->get(); //finally get the result

    return view('frontend.category')->with('results', $results );
```

What is the problem in here ! Structure , search query or logic ?
 (I'm using php laravel 5 , mysql-InnoDB)
Thanks for HELP!

Comment: Well that's one reason EAV is considered an anti-pattern. Use a database like you're supposed to: with real columns.

Comment: Remove criteria with 'like' keyword and see if encountering same performance issue.

Comment: hımm , what should i use instead of `like` ?  `=` ?

Comment: If you don't need EAV, don't use it. If you do need EAV, bear in mind that a nice chunk of things possible with relational design won't be possible with EAV - such as searches. They will be painfully slow, if even possible to write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `eav` model for your `searchable` fields. And if you have lots `fields` and need to `filter` them like me , try to use a search engine like `ElasticSearch` for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

EAV sucks.

Decide on a few columns that are typically searched on, and that have good selectivity.  Put them in columns in the main table.  Decide on a few compound indexes.  Put the rest of the fields into JSON in a single extra column.  Use MySQL to filter on the attributes that have columns, then PHP to finish the filtering with the JSON data.

[More discussion in my EAV blog.](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav)